# TFS Analysis Services Sync job fails due to Perspectives feature not available

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to clean up some issues we are having with our installation of Team Foundation Server 2012.  The Best Practices Analyzer has been invaluable in tracking down issues but one has me stumped:

> Full Analysis Database Sync job has failed with the following error:"[Full Analysis Database Sync]:  --->
>     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseException: TF221122: An error occurred running job Full Analysis Database Sync for team project collection or Team Foundation server TEAM FOUNDATION. ---> 
>     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseException: TF221048: The Analysis Services database Tfs_Analysis on the server SERVERNAME cannot be accessed by DOMAIN\User. ---> 
>     Microsoft.AnalysisServices.OperationException: Errors related to feature availability and configuration: The 'Perspectives' feature is not included in the '64 Bit Standard' edition of Analysis Services.
>     Errors in the metadata manager. An error occurred when loading the Code Churn perspective, from the file, '\?\d:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS11.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data\Tfs_Analysis.0.db\Team System.2.cub\Perspective.2.persp.xml'.
>
> at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.CheckForException(XmlReader reader, XmlaResult xmlaResult, Boolean throwIfError)
>     at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AnalysisServicesClient.Discover(IMajorObject obj, ObjectExpansion expansion)
>     at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server.Refresh(IMajorObject obj, ObjectExpansion expansion)
>     at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.MajorObject.get_Body()
>     at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Database.get_Body()
>     at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Database.get_Cubes()
>     at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.TFSOlapProcessComponent.GetLastProcessedTimeStamp(String serverName, String dbName)
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.TFSOlapProcessComponent.GetLastProcessedTimeStamp(String serverName, String dbName)
>     at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.TFSOlapProcessComponent.DetermineProcessType(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, AnalysisDatabaseProcessingType desiredProcessingType, Boolean& lastProcessingFailed, Boolean& needCubeSchemaUpdate)
>     at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.AnalysisDatabaseSyncJobExtension.RunInternal(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime queueTime, String& resultMessage)
>     at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseJobExtension.Run(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime queueTime, String& resultMessage)
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---". The failure occurred at 12/14/2015 20:42:57.'

There was some confusion regarding which license we had when this server was set up:  Originally SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition was installed, but it was replaced with 2012 Standard Edition.

I have already tried stopping the Analysis Service and deleting the `Tfs_Analysis.0.db` folder then restarting the service.

The TFS Admin Console shows Analysis Services Database as *Configured and Jobs Enabled* and the `Perspective.2.persp.xml` file no longer exists (in fact, the `Team System.2.cub` directory no longer exists either) but the error persists in the Best Practices Analyzer.

I'm stuck with Standard Edition so going back to Enterprise Edition is not a viable solution.  Are there other things to try before falling back on an uninstall/reinstall of TFS?

** UPDATE **

I have tried using the WarehouseControlWebService as well.  If I invoke `BringWarehouseProcessingOnline` or `BringAnalysisProcessingOnline` they return `Started` but `GetProcessingStatus` returns this error:

> [Incremental Analysis Database Sync]: ---> TF221106: Reporting for Team Foundation Server cannot execute job Incremental Analysis Database Sync for TEAM FOUNDATION because the Analysis Services processing is offline. Use the Team Foundation Administration Console to start reporting.

This is all well and good except, of course, the Reporting tab shows everything as Configured.

Comment: Two things you can have a try first: 1). Connect to Analysis Services, right-click Tfs_Analysis cube and click Process. 2). Expand the Tfs_Analysis node, and then expand the Roles node, add user to the TFSWarehouseDataReader role.

Comment: @Vicky-MSFT, could you submit your comment as an answer?

Comment: add an answer reply with my comment content. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you can have a try first: 1). Connect to Analysis Services, right-click Tfs_Analysis cube and click Process. 2). Expand the Tfs_Analysis node, and then expand the Roles node, add user to the TFSWarehouseDataReader role.

Comment: This solved the immediate problem.  Unfortunately, it only uncovered other errors so we decided it was time to cut our losses and reinstall.  Accepting as it addressed the specific question I asked.

Answer (score 1):

Try to rebuild the data warehouse and Analysis database: open the TFS Administration console, click on Reporting node, click on **Start Rebuild** option from the right area.

Comment: I tried this and still encounter the same issue.  I know when you click the _Start Rebuild_ button there is a warning that rebuilding could take a "significant" amount of time.  Would this job have to finish before the error would clear?  And if so, what would be a reasonable amount of time to allow for this to happen?  We have three users and about a dozen projects in one collection.

Comment: The rebuild time depends on your collection size. On my production instance it took 3 days to re build it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to follow the article below to manually process data warehouse and analysis services cube for Team Foundation Server. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400237.aspx

If manually processing still received the same issue, you can try to delete the Tfs_Analysis database and recreate it using TFS Admin Console. To delete the Tfs_Analysis database, you can connect to **Analysis Service** using **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**, expand the **Databases** node, and delete the Tfs_Analysis database.

To recreate the Tfs_Analysis database, please refer to the following steps:

1. Launch TFS Admin Console>>Application Tier>>Reporting, in the right panel, click **Edit** to open the **Reporting** windows.
2. Under the **Analysis Services** tab, input the Tfs_Analysis under **Database** textbox, and re-provide the required account under **Account for accessing data source**.
3. Click **Ok** to generate the Tfs_Analysis database in **Analysis Services**.
4. Click **Start Jobs** and **Start Rebuild** to rebuild warehouse and the Analysis Services database.